# Extraction datas from forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I've just start to learn Django and now I'm trying understand how to insert datas in db, how to work with datas from templates and ect.
My question is about extracting datas from form(Meta class) in template.

Here is my code:

model

```
class Worker(models.Model):
POSITION_SHOICE = (
    ('MANAGER', 'MANAGER'),
    ('developer', 'DEVELOPER'),
    ('teamlead', 'TEAMLEAD'),
    ('pm', 'PM'),
    ('hr', 'HR'),
)
f_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
s_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
position = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=POSITION_SHOICE, default='developer')
work_time = models.DecimalField(max_digits=1000, decimal_places=0)
cost_in_hour = models.DecimalField(max_digits=1000, decimal_places=2)

salary = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10000000, decimal_places=2, default=0)
```

before inserting datas salaty should be calculate in this way:
salary = work_time*cost_in_hour

form

```
class WorkerForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Worker
    fields = {
        'f_name',
        's_name',
        'position',
        'work_time',
        'cost_in_hour',
    }
```

view

```
def worker_create_view(request):
form = WorkerForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    form = WorkerForm()
context = {
    'form': form
}
return render(request, "workers/worker_create.html", context)
```

I actually cannot understand how can I extract datas from dictionary items with name 'work_time' and          'cost_in_hour'. then calculate salary, insert into dictionary and send to database.

P.S. if you can explain or write a resource where can i read about how does inserting datas work in Django it'd be cool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering from the android. Later will put this on proper "code" form.

On your:

```
 if form.is_valid():
      instance = form.save(commit=False)

      #do what you want with the form fields like
       instance.salary = instance.work_time *cost_in_hour
      # then
       instance.save()

      #continue to response
```

Later will explain better

You can also override the form save method on the form itself for a more clean view.

Hope I could help

Comment: No problem, see also form clean and init if you didn’t by now. Formsets are a pretty useful feature for you in the future aswell