# how can I modify form model data in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to send data from Form but can't send a specific data

for example:
in my model has a student that I want send separate from view

in view:

```
student = Student.objects.filter(id=id) 
if request.method == "POST":
    form = StudentProject(request.POST, files=request.FILES)
    form.student_id=id
    form.save()
    return redirect('main')
```

in form:

```
class Meta:
    model=Project
    fields=['name','link','image','body','term']
```

in model:

```
name=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False)
link=models.CharField(max_length=1000,null=False)
image=models.ImageField(upload_to='static/project/images/')
body=models.TextField()
term=models.DecimalField(max_digits=1,decimal_places=0,null=False)
student=models.ForeignKey(Student,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
created_at=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Comment: Does this answer respond to your needs?https://stackoverflow.com/a/59805510/10029164 could you elaborate your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I can modify `ModelForm` in `django` like this:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name=forms.CharField(label="Name",widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class':'form-control',
        }
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send specific data, then exclude all the fields that you don't want to be on the form. Suppose I only want the name of the project:

```py
class Meta:
    model = Project
    fields = ['name']
```

> in my model has a student that I want send separate from view

I think the cleanest way to do this is to separate your initial form into two, create two views, and have the user input it separately.

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't relate to Meta Class